# Slideshow Effect with 3 Images per slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me.

I'm trying to find out a way to use the Javascript slideshow effect as show in the code below, however, instead of incorporating one quote onto each slide I'm trying to get 3 Images (Including headings for each) per slide. I'm trying so hard to do this but its just not working out.

**html**

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides">
    <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
    <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
  </div>
  
<div class="mySlides">
  <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
  <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
  <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
height: 250px;
width: 100%;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
    
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(145, 144, 144, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {font-style: italic;
}

/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {color: cornflowerblue;}
```

**Javascript**

```
// JavaScript Document
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: it's not clear! your current slider dynamically adapts to the width of the display, we cannot do this with the images except to distort or truncate them, and in addition you want to have 3 images per slide, which would make 9 at total.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
    .mySlides {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
    }
</style>
<div class="mySlides">
    <div>
        <h2>Image Heading</h2>
        <img src="..." />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Image Heading</h2>
        <img src="..." />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Image Heading</h2>
        <img src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```